# Need help understanding the Triple Step dynamic programming / recursion question

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I been trying to learn/understand more of dynamic programming / recursion, but I am not sure how to wrap my head around why this works. I am working on this

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-reach-nth-stair-using-step-1-2-3/

which has the solution in the link. I understand recursion to a point, but I am not understanding how the the structure of the program gives the result you want. I just, can't see why

```
return findStep(n - 3) +  
       findStep(n - 2) + 
       findStep(n - 1);
```

solves this, or how someone would know it would give you all the possibilities.

The memorize part of the code is showed later, but I wanted to just show the basics.

any help is appreciate, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of people who haven't followed your link, the problem you're trying to solve is to find how many different ways there are of ascending a staircase by hopping up 1, 2 or 3 steps at a time (in any combination).

Let's use the notation *f*(*x*) to represent the number of possible ways of climbing a staircase of *x* steps, and suppose you're at the bottom of a staircase with *n* steps. You have three options for your next move:

- If you go up one step, then there will be *f*(*n*-1) possible ways of climbing the stairs from your new position.
- If you go up two steps, then there will be *f*(*n*-2) possible ways of climbing the stairs from your new position.
- If you go up three steps, then there will be *f*(*n*-3) possible ways of climbing the stairs from your new position.

If all three of these actions are possible, then the value of *f*(*n*) must be equal to *f*(*n*-1) + *f*(*n*-2) + *f*(*n*-3). This is the basis of the recursion algorithm. All you have to provide is the end-point:

- *f*(1) = 1 (ascend 1 step)
- *f*(2) = 2 (ascend 2 steps, or 1+1 steps)
- *f*(3) = 4 (ascend 3 or 2+1 or 1+2 or 1+1+1 steps)

If you like, you could also add the condition that *f*(0) = 1 (i.e., there is one way of *not* ascending a staircase). The code in the page you linked to seems to have folded the results for *f*(3) and *f*(0) together, but the results will be the same.

Since this recursive algorithm calls itself 3 times at each iteration, it will run very slowly unless you store the intermediate values of *f*(*x*). This is what memoization in dynamic programming is for.